# Custom Edit Action in Customer Grid(Custom)

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i link this **Edit** action to a custom block.

**Code**

```
   class  <Namespace>_<Module>_Block_Adminhtml_Stylist_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
   {

     protected function _prepareCollection()
     {
     parent::_prepareCollection();
     $loginUserId = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId();
     $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('stylist_id', $loginUserId);
     $this->setCollection($collection);
     return $this; } }
```

[image]

Comment: mean `custom block.` want to show  custom block when click on **Edit** link

Comment: yes, on clicking edit a custom block has to be shown.

Comment: on new pages... > i am right

Comment: Yes, a page like customer edit (Page with sidebar)